# What is a sans-serif font that still clearly differentiates similar characters like: l 1, i etc

Tags: font

I am looking for an easy-to-read  San Serif font that manages to make the normally similar looking characters (o, 0;   1,l,i) still clearly differniated to the eye.

This sill be used for very short text lengths (letters, word, or maybe a sentence)
(For longer passages we may consider a Serif font)

Any suggestions?

Update:  One of the other "gotchas" is  capital I

Here is some good sample test with which to test:

```
I would like 1 little icicle
```

Comment: Look through some fonts designed specifically for writing code.

Comment: Although this could be asked on another site, it is clearly about he UX of fonts rather than their visual appeal, so I consider it on topic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider the following fonts:

- Droid Sans
- PT Sans
- Noto Sans
- Ubuntu

Here's a preview: http://typecast.com/preview/google/Noto%20Sans/Droid%20Sans/PT%20Sans/Ubuntu

They are all available on [Google Fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts).

Comment: Arvo and PT Sans seem to meet my criteria the best.

Answer (score 15):

## [Source Sans Pro](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Source+Sans+Pro)

Source Sans Pro was Adobe's first open source font face and meets your criteria where the lowercase l curves while the uppercase I remains straight.

[image: source sans pro]

---

### Does serif vs. sans-serif really make a difference?

This article titled, "[Which Are More Legible: Serif or Sans Serif Typefaces?](http://alexpoole.info/blog/which-are-more-legible-serif-or-sans-serif-typefaces/)" rightfully concludes ...

> It is of course *possible* that serifs or the lack of them have an effect on legibility, but it is *very likely* that they are so peripheral to the reading process that this effect is not even worth measuring.
>
> There are also other factors such as x-height, counter size, letter spacing and stroke width which are more significant for legibility than the presence or absence of serifs.
>
> Finally, we should accept that **most reasonably designed typefaces in mainstream use will be equally legible**, and that it makes much more sense to argue in favour of serif or sans serif typefaces on aesthetic grounds than on the question of legibility.

What's a "reasonably designed" font face?

Here are the top 5 fonts linked to on Google Fonts.  Open Sans is number 1 and I really like how well it utilizes letter spacing to stroke width.

[image: top 5 fonts]

Comment: GREAT answer, complete with clever example. Thanks!

Comment: Argg... bummer, capital I looks like a one or a lower case l in Source Sans Pro.

Comment: The lowercase el is actually a little taller and curves at the bottom while the uppercase i is a perfectly straight line.  Droid Sans looks good on mobile devices and has serif on the uppercase i -- https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Droid+Sans

Answer (score 0):

There is also a CSS enhancement that tweaks fonts that don't distinguish zero from O very effectively:

http://thenewcode.com/656/Generate-Distinct-Zeros-On-Web-Pages-With-OpenType